# Can some explain to me why this property is true for left-continuous RW

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, stochastic-processes

Source Durrett, http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/EOSP/EOSP2E.pdf, page 170 example 5.12.

I don't understand how his implications (i),(ii) imply that there exists an $\alpha \lt 0 \:s.t\: \phi(\alpha)=1$.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Please make your question self-contained, one should not have to go to EOSP2E.pdf page 170 to know what you are talking about.

Comment: @Did sorry to offend you, Ill make sure to do it henceforth

Comment: *Offend*? This is quite off the mark. Make sure instead to do it **now**, on **this** question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is using continuity of the moment generating function $\phi(\theta)=\exp(\theta X_i)$. He states that $\phi(\theta)<1$ for small negative $\theta$, so choose $\alpha_1<0$ with $\phi(\alpha_1)<1$. But $\phi(\theta) \to \infty$  as $\theta \to -\infty$ so choose $\alpha_2<0$ with $\phi(\alpha_2)>1$. Then by continuity of $\phi$, there is $\alpha$ between $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ (in particular, $\alpha<0$) with $\phi(\alpha)=1$.

Comment: Thanks so much, that clears up alot